# Normal/Bump maps causing flat shading

Tags: shaders, normals, smooth, bump

[image]Whenever I add a normal/bump map to a smooth object the shading goes flat. Even on a UV sphere the issue remains. The shader is only using procedural textures so I can't change anything to non-color like a lot of posts suggest. I've used these exact same nodes in previous projects and haven't had this issue before.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share an object that has the problem?

Comment: Hi moonboots, I've added an image for reference to the post

Comment: Yes that's weird, I can't reproduce the problem, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Added the blend file under the reference image

Comment: I don't think that there's any problem, it's the Metallic at 1 plus the Coat that makes it look like it's flat because of the reflectivity, it may be not very realistic though

Comment: The file is a basic node setup to display the issue. When setting the values to less than .1 in the test file there are still lines visible so I don't think this is the solution.  The original shader in another file had more appropriate values in the normal map but that was when I noticed the issue. Weirdly enough, the shader was appended from another project and was completely fine in that file.

Comment: could you please share the other file you are talking about?

Comment: Also, remember that it is a bump map, not real 3D, if you subdivide your object and give it a Displace modifier it won't look flat, bump and normal map are limited in terms of realism

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the other file as it's too large and also work for a client. 

I understand that this is a bump map. The shader in this image is for test purposes to display the issue I'm having. Even when I subdivide the mesh further it is still flat if there is a normal map applied. I've never had this issue before when using normals and I can't figure out why it's happening.

Comment: Subdivising the mesh won't change anything for the bump map, I was talking about giving it a Displace modifier, here you see that it won't appear flat

Comment: Make it slightly less black and it will work better

Comment: This isn't flat shading, it's just *wrong* shading.  You are sending it normals that don't make any sense-- not normalized, no relation to existing tangents-- and so when you use those colors as a normal map, you end up with normals that don't make any sense.  The edges become visible because tangents change at edges.  If you want more info, I'd recommend learning more about how tangent space normals work.